# Receive multiple client request in aRest arduino as web server

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I am pretty new with Arduino, I am stuck with Arduino code where I need to receive multiple sequential request from client and update value in Arduino board. I am using Ethernet board with Arduino and aRest library to expose Arduino board with RESTFul services.

Please check below code and let me know what should I modify or edit to achieve below requirements (note that I have commented watchdog related code),

https://gist.github.com/shaikhmshariq/36264bf20f24faf078c4155542fc6836

I need to receive multiple (sequential) requests from client through EthernetClient and update Motor speed based on received input. When I run the code below,

- With watchdog - it resets the board and because of it motor shuts down after 4 seconds that is not what I want.
- Without watchdog- it doesn't receive second request at all, which means server doesn't respond at all after serving first request for which I receive instant response from server.

Comment: What is the meaning of voting down the question without any comment ? What is missing here ?

Comment: Can you show the code and/or the request you're making? You may not me closing the connection before sending the second one, try adding this header to your request: `Connection: close` to finish the connection right after sending the value.

Comment: Hi George. I was able to figure out the problem and I will be sharing my findings on this soon. Though code you can see from the link I have shared from Github. As I was not able to put code here due to formatting problems I have shared it on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being late on this but here is my finding about the problem above I was facing.

So it was nothing to do with the code base, it looks like there was some problem (mostly with my resistor) with my circuit so when I was calling `analogWrite` with value higher than 80 duty cycle it was causing my `EthernetServer` to hung forever. I have tested with values between 0 to 80 duty value and it was working fine as per the expectation.

I was able to achieve the required behavior with 0 to 80 duty cycle for my POC so didn't corrected my circuit. Hope this helps someone to troubleshoot similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't access you code from here due to proxy problems, however I faced similar problem long time ago when I tried to configure my board as a server. Basically the reason why my service was stop responding the second request was lack of memory. Refactoring my code and make use of timers instead of controling everthing from a main code helped me to overcome the problem. Try to use below's libary to keep you eyes on your memory.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory